# Issue with C++ Executable: While loop and If/Else If/Else

Tags: c++

So, for robotics, the programming team is learn a new language, C++ instead of Objective Robotic C, and in order to learn the language, we are creating our own Text Based Roleplaying Games. I have started creating mine and have run into an issue. I have to program ask for a Y or an N and then detect which one it is in order to move on with that game. The detection system is inside of a while loop, so that way if it gets an answer other than Y or N it will restart loop. However, when it runs it, it only seems to detect the N. Anything else I put in for the answer triggers the "Yes" option. I'm guessing it is something super obvious I am missing. Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int loop1 = 0;
    string name;
    string cont;

    cout << "[WARNING: Incoming Message]\n";
    sleep(2);
    cout << "[Communication Link Ping]\n";
    sleep(2);
    cout << "[ERROR: Encrypted]\n";
    sleep(2);
    cout << "[Please Enter Security Name]\n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "[Welcome, " << name << ", Security Level: Maximum]\n"
    sleep(2);

    while (loop1 == 0) {
        cout << "[Proceed? Y/N]\n";
        cin >> cont;
        if (cont == "N" || cont == "n") {
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (cont == "Y" || "y") {
            cout << "[Processing...]\n";
            sleep(2);
            cout << "[Thank you, " + name + ", message incoming.]\n";
            loop1 = 1;
        }
        else if (cont == "") {
            cout << "[Please enter a valid input]\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "[Processing...]\n";
            sleep(2);
            cout << "[Unknown Input]\n";
        };
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's very low quality and can be found everywhere, thus no research from the user.

Comment: @gsamaras I disagree OP could have overlooked the issue, plus OP said he/she is beginner

Comment: That's why tutorials exist @GiorgiMoniava, moreover, if you search the net you will find a ton of similar questions....

Comment: @gsamaras Ok no point in discussing this further. We can disagree. Though this is not the type of problem you find in tutorials.

Comment: i'm sorry if i irritated you, ive looked at this code all day and couldnt find it. i am a beginner and did do a ton of research, but i thought it was a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test is always true:

```
else if(cont == "Y" || "y")
```

because `"y"` always evaluates to non-zero, therefore `(cont == "Y" || "y")`
 always evaluates to non zero.

You wanted:

```
else if(cont == "Y" || cont ==  "y")
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

```
else if(cont == "Y" || "y")
```

should be

```
else if(cont == "Y" ||  cont == "y")
```

Explanation: OR operator returns true if one of its operands if true, clearly simply using literal "y" returns true - because it is address in memory and not 0.

Comment: I believe it should be: `if (toupper(cont[0]) == 'Y')`, but then, I believe in converting to one case so there are fewer compares.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that is even better

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I hate finding the tiny little errors in my code. I had my team scour through, and no one caught it. I was having my captain look through it and then I had to leave. Thanks! It worked. ++

Answer (score 0):

If you convert or *transform* the input string to all lower case or all upper case, you would only need one compare:

```
cont[0] = toupper(cont[0]);
if (cont[0] == 'Y')
```

Search the internet for "c++ string transform lower case" for examples.